# how to use WordNet in C#?

Tags: c#, ontology, wordnet, synset

I want to find out synonyms of a specific word Like "help". The synonyms of help are "aid", "assist" or "assistance" etc.

I have downloaded the Wordnet library and used this in Visual Studio.

1. Create new project
2. Download library of Wordnet using Manage NuGet Packages.
3. Work with this code:

   ```
   WordNetEngine wne = new WordNetEngine();
   PartOfSpeech pos = new PartOfSpeech();
   SynSet ss = new SynSet(pos, 0, wne);
   Console.WriteLine("words form wordnet" + ss.Words);
   ```

But this is not working.

Please can anyone help me in this regard with code example in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: //Read the file and display it line by line.  
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Ahmad\Downloads\wn3.1.dict\dict\dbfiles\noun.food");
            while ((line1 = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(line1);
                counter++;
            }        This code read file data but i don't know how to find out synonyms .

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if you are still interested in this question, but these two Nuget Packages will help you:

https://developer.syn.co.in/tutorial/wordnet/tutorial.html

https://github.com/curiosity-ai/catalyst

In addition, please review the WordNet site for a complete guide about using the lexical database.